# PHP Reading in a text file using explode() to get specific parts of text

Tags: php, css, html

So i have two text files, one called users.txt and schedule.txt. The schedule.txt looks like this: (Note the numbers above are not in the file, they are used as a reference from for the user file)

```
   0           1     2
```

2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00

```
    3          4     5     6
```

2013-07-21^10:00|15:00|18:00|15:00

```
    7          8
```

2013-12-11^13:00|14:00

and the users.txt file looks like this:

John Smith^2|4|6

Star Wars^0|1|3|6

Luke Skywalker^2|6|7|8

and each of those numbers corresponds to the index of the other file...so for example John Smith has a time 14:00 on 2013-04-11 (from the 2), a time of 15:00 (from the 4) and so forth...

Well Im building a table for all of this using HTML and I am having trouble extracting the values for the time (ex 12:00).

Also I am very NEW to html and PHP so please go easy on me...please if you have pointers or any other useful information please share =) I will definitly be needing it when I try to add an edit (for editing times to this using radio buttons) and adding a new user.

Thank You so much for any help/advice!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Scheduler</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h2>
<center>Select Your Meeting Times</center></h2>
    <table border="1"
    cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <?php 
    //error_reporting(0);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    // used for displaying schedule times 
        $schedule= file('schedule.txt');
        // loop through array and output contents

        foreach($schedule as $s) {
            list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $s); 
            $ga = explode("|", $s);
            var_dump($year); 
            //echo $ga[5];


                            $year= intval($year, 10);
            $month= intval($month, 10);
            $day= intval($day, 10); 

            $h = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day,$year);
            $d = date("F dS, Y", $h); //used to get the day of the week 
            $w= date("l", $h); // w now holds the day of the week.

            foreach($schedule as $t)
            {   
                // $split = preg_split('/| /', $t, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);



                list($time) = explode("|", $t); 
                list($time1) = explode(" ", $time); 
            //  var_dump($time1); 
            //  $output = trim($time1); 
            //  echo $test; 
                echo "<th>" . $w . "<br>" . $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year . "</th>\n";


            }




        }


    ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <?php
            $text = file('user.txt');
            // loop through array and output contents
            foreach($text as $user) {
                list($u) = explode('^', $user);
                echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $u . "</td>" . "</tr>\n";
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th><br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    </table>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's far from clear how your two tables relate to each other. How does John Smith get a time of 15:00 from an index of 4? I just don't see it. Can I suggest you simplify this and get a handle on it yourself before trying to code something?

Comment: the sooner you switch to a RDBMS the better

Comment: how big is your `schedule.txt`? can it be stored in memory? I also support @Dagon's suggestion

Comment: `a time of 15:00 (from the 4)` <-- can you explain how? still very unclear

Comment: sorry guys.. the way I am doing it is for a requirement... have to use two text files. The schedule.txt file is assumed to exist already from what I have listed already present.

Comment: What that means is when you look at the users file and it has a number.. thats in index value of the schedule file... so going through schedules file 0 is the date, 1 is a time, 2 is a time ... and so forth   So for like John Smith he has a 2, by counting on the schedule file... go over 2 starting at 0 you see his time is then 4:00

Comment: do you mean `2013-04-11`<--0 `12:00`<--1 `4:00`<--2 `14:00`<--3 `2013-07-21`<--4 `10:00`<--5 etc? if not please edit your question and add the index of each item below it. it will be more helpful.

Comment: yes that is right..okay i will thank you!

Comment: if `John Smith has a time 14:00 on 2013-04-11 (from the 2)` is time `4:00` then i think i understood you somewhat

Comment: Yes that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this this way. If you want to use text files (for a small app that's OK) then use a sensible text format. Do away with all these custom delimiters and just use CSV format (where you can use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read a line into an array), or better, use [JSON](http://www.json.org) format with proper tags (use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to unpack it) and your trouble in extracting times will evaporate.

You also don't need all that malarkey extracting dates - look up [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and make life easy on yourself.

Comment: The guy clearly stated he's a newb... Could you elaborate on what a "sensible text format" is?

Answer (score 0):

People above have already commented on a better way to store information, but to answer you question about extract():

when you do

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', "2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00");
```

you get `"11^12:00|4:00|14:00"` for the value of `$day`, not `"11"`. And similarly, when you do

```
$ga = explode("|", "2013-04-11^12:00|4:00|14:00");
```

you get `"2013-04-11^12:00"` as the first value. Judging from the rest of your code, this is probably not how you intend it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small class for you. I have not included any error checking. still bit confused about the first time after `^` so i have added comment in the code on how to include it. Also note i have not commented the code, hope you will understand it.

```
class UserTime{
    var $data=array();
    function __construct(){
        $lines = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        foreach ($lines as $l){
            list($d,$t)=explode('^', $l);
            $this->data[]=$d;
            $t=explode('|', $t);
            // you have to remove the following line if you want to
            // include the first time after ^
            array_shift($t);
            $this->data = array_merge($this->data,$t);
        }
    }
    function getUser($user_string){
        list($user_name,$ix)=explode('^', $user_string);
        $userData['userName']=$user_name;
        $userData['time']=array();
        $idx = explode('|', $ix);
        for($i=0;$i<count($idx);$i++){
            if(isset($this->data[$idx[$i]])){
                $userData['time'][]=$this->data[$idx[$i]];
            }
        }
        return $userData;
    }
}
```

you can use the class as below

```
$users = new UserTime();
$udata = $users->getUser('John Smith^2|4|6');
print_r($udata);
$udata = $users->getUser('Star Wars^0|1|3|6');
print_r($udata);
```

the output is as follows. I think you can use this yourselves in your HTML.

```
Array
(
    [userName] => John Smith
    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14:00
            [1] => 15:00
            [2] => 15:00
        )

)
```

Comment: I sill didn't properly understand how all these works and what output you want exactly.

Comment: Thank You for your effort! What I am trying to do is have a table of all the users on left side and have the times up top as headers. When there is a number on the users file its going to put a check mark in the box containing the time from the schedule.. this is ultimately going to change when I add an edit button for user so that they can select the table block (using radio buttons) which will write to the file and then pull the schedule file back in... hope that clears up